# How to read two shorthand if statements connected with an equal strict?

Tags: javascript

I was looking through [moment.min.js](http://momentjs.com/downloads/moment.min.js) when I ran into an expression that looked like this:

```
return A ? B : C === D ? E : F
```

Literally, I would read that as `when this function is called, return the result of if A then B, else C, must strictly equal if D then E, else F`, but even if that's correct, I am not sure exactly what that does.

How is that read and what would the expression do?

Comment: Why would someone downvote this question?  Synonymous with Stack site are herds of bitter nerds.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
return A ? B : ((C === D) ? E : F);
```

Maybe it's easier to understand with those parentheses (evaluates to the same). The exact representation of the code above with if-else statements are:

```
if (A == true) {
   return B;
} else {
   if (C === D) {
     return E;
   } else {
     return F;
   } 
}
```

I could also write `return (A ? B : ((C===D) ? E : F));` The point is that if **A** wont evaluate to true, then another ternary operator is evaluated. Those parentheses just separate them from the other one, but they are absolutely not neccessary.

`return (A ? B : C) === (D ? E : F);` In this case we compare the evaluation of two ternary operators, and return it's result, which is a completely different story.

Comment: How did you come up with those parentheses?  Why not `return (A ? B : C) === (D ? E : F);` or `return (A ? B : C === D) ? E : F;`?  Is it just because it doesn't make sense?  If we had an expression like `1 + 2 * 3 - 4 / 5 + 6` we wouldn't simply conclude it was `1 + 2 * ((3 - 4) / 5 + 6)`...

Answer (score 2):

It test if `A` is truthy (a number !== 0, a not empty string, an object, not `null`, not `undefined`) then return `B`. If not, then check if `C` is strict equal `D`, return `E` otherwise `F`

```
if (A) {
    return B;
} else if (C === D) {
    return E;
} else {
    return F;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Apply syntax precedence, to get:

```
return (A ? B : ((C === D) ? E : F))
```

Is `A` truthy? Yes? Great, return `B`.

Oh, it's not? Then depending on whether `C` is strictly equal to `D`, return either `E` or `F`.

The author should not have written such confusing shorthand, and this question is why.